# Вывод фамилий содержащих две гласные буквы

Tags: c++, строки

Я столкнулся с трудностями при решении задачи: С введенного с клавиатуры списка фамилий вывести имеющие две гласные буквы. Вот код, но он не работает:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int count;
    char str[100], s[100];
    char gl[10] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    cout << "Введите список фамилий\n";
    cin.getline(str, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s[i] = str[i];
        count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= strlen(gl); k++) {
                if (s[j] == gl[k]) count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            cout << s << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу помощи в поиске багов или решении задачи.

Comment: `char str[100]` это же массив из 100 элементов типа `char`, а не 100 строк

Comment: `strlen(gl)` не будет работать, так как gl - не нуль-терминированная строка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string gl = "aeiouAEIOU"; // По строке удобнее итерироваться, ведь не надо задавать константу с размером, как в случае с массивом символов
    int count;
    cout << "Введите количество фамилий:" << endl;
    cin >> count;
    string surnames[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // Вводим каждую фамилию
        cin >> surnames[i];    
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        string str = surnames[i];
        int gl_count = 0; // Количество гласных

        for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < gl.size(); k++) {
                if (str[j] == gl[k]) gl_count++;
            }
        }

        if (gl_count == 2) {
            cout << str << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но количество фамилий я задал вручную т.к. длина строки должна быть константой